# Identity out of order with system versioned table

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment, temporal-tables

I'm using [system-versioned (temporal) tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) with an identity column and noticed that sometimes the start time of a row in the history table has a higher identity value than a row with a later start time. See example below:

| StartTime | EndTime | Identity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-21 14:10:25.4181267 | 2022-09-21 16:32:14.5724582 | 2 |
| 2022-09-21 14:10:26.1524526 | 2022-09-21 15:46:19.6136239 | 1 |

Is this because of overlapping transactions - i.e one row "claimed" the earlier identity value but was then inserted slightly after another set of values?

Comment: "The system sets the value for the ValidFrom column to the begin time of the current transaction" which means that if there is a delay in between tran1 starting and inserting, in which tran2 starts and inserts, then yes there will be an overlap. Why does it matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter in itself, it's more something I didn't necessarily expect so I thought it would be worthwhile to clarify what the actual expected behaviour is. Thank you for the clarification, I was struggling to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the document you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16)

> **INSERTS:** The system sets the value for the ValidFrom column to the begin time of the current transaction...

But `IDENTITY` columns take their values at the moment of insertion. So yes, there may be an overlap.